# updating a database record doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I'm trying to put events of our coverband in a database. I want to correct the typo of every record, if required for any case. [Here is a live version of the webapp](http://davyschouw.nl/webapp/)

The problem is: I have made a link to change the record called: "wijzig agendapunt" in the index.php file (which is working fine). A php file takes the text from database and puts it in a form(so far so good). When I think everything is correct I press: "wijzig". Then another php file starts to update in database with correct text. But here it goes wrong.

I hope you guys can help me! Thank you! :)

Code snippet for database connection:

**connect.php**

```
<?php
  try {
   $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=davyschouw_app",       
   'davyschouw_app', '***');
// set the PDO error mode to exception
   $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  }
catch(PDOException $e)
 {
  echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
 }
?>
```

Then the php file with the form:

**editmarker.php**

```
<body>

<?php
include "connect.php";

    $record_name = $_GET["id"];


    echo $record_name;

    $sth = $conn -> prepare("

        SELECT *
        FROM addmarker
        WHERE id = :record_name

    ");

    $sth -> bindValue( ":record_name", $record_name, PDO::PARAM_STR );

    $sth -> execute();

    $printRecord = $sth -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    /*
    //dit record als array weergeven
    print("<pre>");
    print_r($printRecord);
    print("</pre>");
    */

    //gegevens in variabelen zetten
    $printRecordRecord = $printRecord[0];
    $huidigeNaam = $printRecordRecord["event"];
    $huidigAdres = $printRecordRecord["address"];
    $huidigeDatum = $printRecordRecord["date"];
    $huidigeSets = $printRecordRecord["sets"];
    $huidigeTijd = $printRecordRecord["time"];
    $huidigeBeschrijving = $printRecordRecord["description"];
    $huidigeLink = $printRecordRecord["tickets"];

    print("

        <form action='editedmarker.php' method='POST'>
            <table>

                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor='green'><b>Naam</b></td>
                    <td bgcolor='green'><b>Adres</b></td>
                    <td bgcolor='green'><b>Datum</b></td>
                    <td bgcolor='green'><b>Sets</b></td>
                    <td bgcolor='green'><b>Tijd</b></td>
                    <td bgcolor='green'><b>Beschrijving</b></td>
                    <td bgcolor='green'><b>Tickets</b></td>
                    <td bgcolor='green'></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><input type='text' name='naam' value='$huidigeNaam'/></td>
                    <td><input type='text' name='address' value='$huidigAdres' /></td>
                    <td><input type='text' name='date' value='$huidigeDatum' /></td>
                    <td><input type='text' name='sets' value='$huidigeSets'/></td>
                    <td><input type='text' name='time' value='$huidigeTijd' /></td>
                    <td><input type='text' name='description' value='$huidigeBeschrijving' /></td>
                    <td><input type='text' name='tickets' value='$huidigeLink' /></td>
                    <td><input type='submit' value='Wijzig' /></td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </form>

    ");

?>

</body>
```

After filling up the form completely I have triggered the next php file. But it doesn't update the data  to the database. I can't figure out why

**editedmarker.php**

```
<head>
<title>Gewijzigd</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php
include "connect.php";

    //geupdate gegevens ophalen
    $newEvent = $_POST["event"];
    $newAddress = $_POST["address"];
    $newDate = $_POST["date"];
    $newSets = $_POST["sets"];
    $newTime = $_POST["time"];
    $newDescription = $_POST["description"];
    $newTickets = $_POST["tickets"];

    //gegevens updaten als ALLES is ingevuld
    if ( ($newEvent != "") && ($newAddress != "") && ($newDate != "") && ($newSets != "")
     && ($newTime != "") && ($newDescription != "") && ($newTickets != "") ) {


        $sth = $conn -> prepare("

            UPDATE addmarker
            SET event = :event,
            address = :address,
            date = :date,
            sets = :sets,
            time = :time,
            description = :description,
            tickets = :tickets
            WHERE event = :event

        ");

        $sth -> bindValue( ":event", $newEvent, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $sth -> bindValue( ":address", $newAddress, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $sth -> bindValue( ":date", $newDate, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $sth -> bindValue( ":sets", $newSets, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $sth -> bindValue( ":time", $newTime, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $sth -> bindValue( ":description", $newDescription, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $sth -> bindValue( ":tickets", $newTickets, PDO::PARAM_STR );

        $sth -> execute();

        $sthCheck = $conn -> prepare("

            SELECT *
            FROM addmarker
            WHERE event = :event

        ");

        $sthCheck -> bindValue( ":event", $newEvent, PDO::PARAM_STR );

        echo "Number of records changed: ".$sthCheck -> execute();

    }
    else {
        echo "NO success";
    }

?>

</body>
```

Comment: echo your query and check direct in database first, If its works there then that should work here too.

Comment: You can't reuse placeholders. (See `:event`).

Comment: You set `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` but you dont run your queries in a try/catch block. So you never bother looking for useful error mesages that PDO would have produced _I think thats called ignoring the bleeping obvious_

Comment: _Also while developing_ Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php/845025#845025) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see if it yields anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From editmarker.php you are not posting `event` attribute. and validating it in editedmarker.php, instead you are posting `naam`. 
you would be getting this error in your error log file,

You should always tail your Error Log file,

Thanks
-Shahram